# LinkedList constructor that allows user to enter the elements in the list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Final Edit: I understand why it wouldn't work now, thanks to everyone that helped.

Edit with answer thanks to ravi, although I still don't fully understand why memory needed to be allocated everytime:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    cin >> input;
    newNode = new Node; //added this to make it work properly
    newNode->info = input;
    newNode->next = cursor;
    cursor = newNode;
}
```

Original Question:

I'm having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how to get this to work.

The question is: IntegerSet(int size): this constructor method creates a new set of size
integers by prompting the user to enter size elements for the set on the keyboard.

As of right now, if size was equal to 3 and the user entered 1, 2, 3, when calling display() the program will only output 3 then end. I commented in the constructor code what I think should be happening which is obviously not behaving like I'm thinking it should. If anyone could explain to me which part (or maybe I am completely off) I am messing up I would appreciate it.

Here is my header:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class IntegerSet
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        T info;
        Node *next;
    };
    typedef Node *nodePtr;
    nodePtr first;
public:
    IntegerSet(int size);
    void display();
};
template <class T>
IntegerSet<T>::IntegerSet(int size)
{
    nodePtr newNode = new Node;
    int input;
    cout << "Enter " << size << " elements" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    newNode->info = input; //sets newNodes first element to input
    newNode->next = 0; //sets newNodes next to null
    nodePtr cursor = newNode; //make a cursor = to newNode, which should be input then 0
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        newNode->info = input; //sets newNodes first element to a new input
        newNode->next = cursor; //sets newNodes next to cursor
        cursor = newNode; //sets cursor = to newNode, so after the first run through of the loop
                          //if the user entered 1 then 2, cursor would be 2->1->0
    }
    cursor->next = 0; //this is only here because it isn't working right in the first place.
                      //If this wasn't here then the program just infinitely loops with the last
                      //element entered when display is called
    first = cursor;
}

template <class T>
void IntegerSet<T>::display()
{
    nodePtr cursor = first;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "There are no elements in the set" << endl;
        return;
    }
    while (cursor != 0)
    {
        cout << cursor->info << " ";
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

main:

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    IntegerSet<int> list(3);
    list.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip (from a non-pro :)) - Don't have user interaction inside a data structure.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils Why is that bad? Also, this is a homework question, so I don't really know how I could keep that from happening without changing the way my professor wants me to do it, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's two things wrong with the way you're doing it. One is you're binding the input/output to cin/cout. If you were to provide io in program it'd be better to allow the user to pass the stream. Second, what if I want a list of 100 items and I don't want to enter them all at this time, which is pretty often the case? Yes, you may have constraints but you can handle that in the main/driver; it would require a little changing but well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    cin >> input;
    newNode->info = input; //sets newNodes first element to a new input
    newNode->next = cursor; //sets newNodes next to cursor
    cursor = newNode; //sets cursor = to newNode, so after the first run through of the loop
                      //if the user entered 1 then 2, cursor would be 2->1->0
}
```

You are not allocating any space for new node in this loop rather you are just overriding first value.And that's why you are getting only last value printed.

Also remove your last line:-

```
cursor->next = 0;
```

Comment: I guess this is what I'm not understanding though. Even if I override first value, I was thinking ->next is pointing to cursor which would have had all the info from the previous newNode stored. I've also tried deleting newNode and redefining it in the loop everytime it is ran if that's what you mean by allocating space, but it ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for explanation rather than code, now.

Try this - Forget about writing it as a computer program, instead draw a linked list on paper. It'll take just three minutes.

You got a number, you created a node in which to store that number, right? And you had to somehow hook it into the list of existing nodes. When you get the next number, you need another node in which to store it, and so on.

Contrast that to your original solution, in which you allocated a node, and rearranged some pointers. Got your next number, put it into the *same* node (losing the previous value), and rearranged some pointers.

See the difference? Draw it out *yourself*, it's worth the time. You can also google "linked list" - there's a decent discussion on wikipedia, among countless other places. But, start with your own drawing!

Comment: Yeah it makes much more sense when you put it like that, and drawing it is a lot easier than trying to visualize all that rearranging in my head. Thanks for the help.